# Plot network without links: the greater the weight of the bond that exists between two nodes, the smaller the distance that separates them in the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, igraph

The following is an example taken from the `igraph` package:

```
library(igraph)
actors <- data.frame(name=c("Alice", "Bob", "Cecil", "David", "Esmeralda"))
relations <- data.frame(from=c("Bob", "Cecil", "Cecil", "David","David", "Esmeralda"),
                        to=c("Alice", "Bob", "Alice", "Alice", "Bob", "Alice"),
                        friendship=c(4,5,5,2,1,1))
g <- graph_from_data_frame(relations, directed=TRUE, vertices=actors)
```

The plot of the graph is the following:

[image]

However, I would like to get a different plot. The aim is to improve the quality and aesthetics of the graphic, for example by using `ggplot2` (or other solutions which I don't know).

The plot should not contain links between nodes: the nodes should be closer to each other, the greater the weight of the link that exists between them. The nodes should have their own label (as depicted in the plot above) and their size should be proportional to the value of the variable `p` of the dataframe `df`.

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(nodes = c("Alice", "Bob", "Cecil", "David", "Esmeralda"
), p = c(4, 3, 2, 2, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

> df
      nodes p
1     Alice 4
2       Bob 3
3     Cecil 2
4     David 2
5 Esmeralda 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

Maybe you can use `visNetwork` package

```
library(visNetwork)

nodes <- transform(
  setNames(df, c("label", "value")),
  id = seq_along(label)
)

edges <- transform(
  relations,
  from = match(from, nodes$label),
  to = match(to, nodes$label),
  length = prod(friendship) / friendship
)

visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
  visEdges(hidden = TRUE)
```

which gives

[image]

---

## Previous Answer

Maybe you can try the code below

```
g %>%
  set_edge_attr(name = "width", value = E(.)$friendship) %>%
  set_vertex_attr(name = "size", value = 10 * with(df, p[match(nodes, names(V(.)))])) %>%
  plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @ThomasIsCoding, it is an interesting solution. But I would like to omit the links and place the nodes in such a way the greater the weight of the link that exists between two nodes, the smaller the distance that separates them in the plot

Comment: @Mark See my update and hope it could help

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to treat the edge value `friendship` as edge `weight`. Internally, these weights are in turn fed to into the standard layout algorithm of `igraph` (`?layout_nicely`; `?layout_with_fr` see `weights` argument):

```
E(g)$weight <- E(g)$friendship^2     # squaring increases the observed effect
plot(g)
```

or as one-liner:

```
plot(g, layout = layout_with_fr(g, weights = E(g)$friendship^2)
```

To omit links you could simply set the color of edges to white:

```
plot(g, 
     layout = layout_with_fr(g, weights = E(g)$friendship^2, 
     edge.color = 'white'))
```

Or in a more elegant solution calculate the layout beforehand and delete the links altogether.

```
l <- layout_with_fr(g, weights = E(g)$friendship^2)
g <- delete.edges(g, which(E(g)$friendship > 0))
plot(g, layout = l)
```